# Общая сумма заказа

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть вот такая структура таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    `id_order` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `dt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `status` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pm` VARCHAR(9) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_order`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `pm` (`pm`)
)
CREATE TABLE `orders_products` (
  `id_order` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_product` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_order`, `id_product`),
INDEX `id_product` (`id_product`),
CONSTRAINT `id_order` FOREIGN KEY (`id_order`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id_order`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `id_product` FOREIGN KEY (`id_product`) REFERENCES `products` (`id_product`)
)
```

Как вывести список заказов и общую сумму заказа, если в одном заказе может быть несколько товаров?

Сделал что-то типа этого, но выводит один заказ несколько раз:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT o.id_order, o.dt, SUM(op.quantity * op.price) as suma_order FROM orders o INNER JOIN orders_products op on o.id_order = op.id_order GROUP BY op.quantity
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну так группировку-то надо делать не по числу заказов, а по самому заказу, т.е. как-то так: `...GROUP BY o.id_order`. Но в таком виде сумма считаться вроде будет неправильно.

SQLFiddle че-то не работает, проверить и показать пример не могу.

Вроде как надо будет сначала делать внутренний селект, чтобы по каждому товару в заказе сумму получить, а во внешнем селекте уже суммировать по заказу.

Чуть позже точнее смогу сказать

Comment: смысл "GROUP BY op.quantity" сможешь объяснить?

Comment: А не, нормально все там. Группировку делаете по заказу как я выше написал и будет вам счастье